# Convertir resultado Timestamp a una fecha

Tags: php, laravel-8

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel 8 y trabajo con una base de datos Mysql. El problema que tengo es que las fechas de las cuentas baneadas Una terminal de un servidor las guarda dentro de la tabla en timestamp y cuando hago una consulta en la vista se muestran los valores 1637096636 no una fecha, como puedo modificar ese resultado en la vista o desde la consulta, gracias por las respuestas

**// Consulta desde el controlador**

```
      $date = DB::connection('mysql2')
            ->table('account_banned')
            ->get();
```

**// vista.blade.php**

```
   @foreach ($ban as $account_banned)
   {{ $account_banned->bandate }}
   @endforeach
```

**// resultado**
1637096636

Como convertir el timestamp a una fecha?

Answer (score 0):

En tu modelo agrega lo siguiente:

```
protected $dates = ['bandate'];
```

Y le das formato de esta forma:

```
@foreach ($ban as $account_banned)
  {{ $account_banned->bandate->format('Y-m-d') }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes trabajar con tu modelo `account_banned` con eloquent y añadir `protected $cast` lo que hara que `bandate` sea transformada.

```
class AccountBanned extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'account_banned';

    protected $casts = [
    'bandate' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];
}
```

luego en tu controlador puedes llamarlo asi en tu funcion

```
$ban = AccountBanned::all();
return view('{tu-vista}', $ban);
```